# Return a reference to an attribute (GCC)

Tags: c++, gcc, reference

I'm using gcc for the first time (previously msvc) and now I have some problems with returning a reference to a variable in my class. Here is the Code:

```
class Foo
{
public:

  const int& getMyVar() const
  {
      return mMyVar;
  }

private:
  int mMyVar;
};
```

If there is a bigger data structure than an simple int I can't imagine that I have to return a copy instead of a reference.

**Here is the compile error**:

> error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'int&' from expression of type 'int'

It would be great if you could help me and show me how I can solve my problem.

Comment: When I add a semicolon to the end and compile the class code shown in the question with GCC 4.7.1 on Mac OS X 10.8.4, I get no errors with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -O3 -c z1.cpp`.  What extra code do you add to get the trouble?  Which version of GCC are you using?  Are you still working on Windows?

Comment: Did you do something like `blahblah = myfoo.getMyVar();`? If so, what's `blahblah` in your code?

Comment: I think you are doing `int &b = foo.getMyVar()`, when you need `const int &b=foo.getMyVar()`.

Comment: g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o main.o main.cpp
my version is 4.7.1 too

Comment: @perreal: I was wondering about whether it was an assignment to an `int &var` too.  But that wouldn't be safe; the value doesn't last beyond the end of the full expression (initialization, in this context), does it?

Comment: no im not using blablabla and no &b ;) just this code example generates the error

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, perhaps I don't understand you. The value should be intact as long as `foo` is in scope?

Comment: @perreal: Oh – you're right; my mistake.  The reference isn't to a function local variable; it is to a member of the variable of the class type.

Comment: the line `return mMyVar;` generates the error

Answer (score 2):

Given the following code, which is a minor variant of your class (constructor added; semicolon added after class) and a simple `main()`, I get the compilation error:

```
z1.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
z1.cpp:19:26: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘int&’ from expression of type  ‘const int’
```

Line 19 is the `const int &v2 = f.getMyVar();` line.  Remove the reference mark, and it is fine.

```
class Foo
{
public:

  Foo(int n = 0) : mMyVar(n) {}
  const int& getMyVar() const
  {
      return mMyVar;
  }

private:
  int mMyVar;
};

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    int  v1 = f.getMyVar(); // Copies result
    int &v2 = f.getMyVar(); // Error: must be const
    const int &v3 = f.getMyVar(); // OK as long as there's a default constructor
    return v1 + v2 + v3;
}
```

Comment: there is no `const int &v2 = f.getMyVar();` at any line.

Comment: Ok, I think i need to add the initialisation as you did. Thank you!

Comment: The constructor is for my sanity; I got the same compilation error (give or take the line number) without the constructor.

Comment: The crazy truth is that it works fine if I add the constructor :D I don't know why but I'm happy that it works.

Answer (score 0):

It will compile without the constructor initialization too.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Foo
{
  int mMyVar;

public:

  const int& getMyVar() const{return mMyVar;}
};

int main()
{
  Foo foo;
  int a = foo.getMyVar();
  const int &b = foo.getMyVar();
  cout<<"My Var a is: "<< a<<endl;
  cout<<"My Var b is: "<< b;
  cin.get();
  return 0;   
}
```